# Unable to start elasticsearch service on Ubuntu WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, installation, wsl2

I installed elasticsearch on WSL2 using the command: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch`  I get the following output:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
Hit:1 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable InRelease
Hit:4 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/swi-prolog/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
elasticsearch is already the newest version (8.4.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdaq2 libdumbnet1 oinkmaster snort-common snort-common-libraries snort-rules-default
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 538 not upgraded.
```

It seems from the above logs that the installation was fine. But I am getting the following error on running the service `sudo service start elasticsearch` I get the following message
`start: unrecognized service`  and same for this command `sudo service elasticsearch start` the output is
`elasticsearch: unrecognized service`
what could be the reason for this?

Comment: @spikey_richie nopes, I updated the OP to make it more clear

Comment: Doesn't the syntax need to be `sudo service elasticsearch start`? The state/action comes after the service name.

Comment: @spikey_richie correct. But I still got the same error

Comment: How about `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch`?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't tried it myself, most people who have asked questions about running Elasticsearch under WSL are using Docker Desktop to do so, although there are other alternatives as well.

As noted in the comments:

- Your first command failed because the syntax for `service` scripts is `sudo service <service_script> command`.
- But that form fails with Elasticsearch because it doesn't provide a service script.  Its package maintainers assume that since you are installing it on Ubuntu, then you are running Systemd.  Which leads us to ...
- WSL doesn't support Systemd without additional configuration.  See my two different answers on [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1379425/1165986) for details.

Two of the alternative options I mention there (when a SysVInit script isn't available) are:

- Use Docker
- Or, if you are running Windows 11, there is a pre-release version of WSL that just came out this week that provides the ability to run Systemd.  Instructions for configuring that are in my second (recent, of course) answer on that Ask Ubuntu question.

Note that if you use Docker to run Elasticsearch, you'll probably need to increase the `max_map_count` configuration as I mention in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69294687/11810933).  Again, the "normal" method of doing this won't work without Systemd.

In addition, as I also mention in the (rather long, I know) Ask Ubuntu answer, it should be possible to run Elasticsearch manually, but you'll need to determine the correct command to do so.